# delete url rewrite database

Tags: database, url, url-rewriting

We are having an array of issues with the url rewrite. There appears to be seo friendly urls forwarding to category pages, then copies of products, some re-directs work others don't and no doubt many more to be uncovered.

It's reached a point where we feel we need to take a backup, scrap/delete and start the url rewrites again, the only problem is we have no idea of what the potential impact could be.

Therefore my question for you kind guru's is, what could possibly go wrong by deleting the url rewrite database?

Comment: Well, the obvious impact is that you could break any / all links that use the rewrite rules. If you make an error in the rules, it could effectively bring the website down depending on how the rules are implemented and what infrastructure (e.g. which web server) you're using.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the quick reply, the plan was to take a back up, and do a bulk 301 upload, if it was to fail then could we not just re-upload the database? thanks again

Comment: There's not enough information to comment really. As for whether trial and error rollbacks are an appropriate mechanism only you can answer.